# Open external link in new tab using results of an LWC Apex call

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

How would I best implement an LWC button that calls an Apex method return a String fragment which I would use to construct a URL (outside of Salesforce= to which I would send the user after the call? The URL should open in a new browser tab.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If its new browser tab, I think it would be simple to use

```
<a href={URL} target="_blank">Go to Site</a>
```

And if it has to go programmatically in callback:

```
var url = this.URL; // get from processing apex response
window.open(url, "_blank");
```